JS Function return undefined why?
I need to add +1 to each card clicked but
Function result 3 as undefined why?
what is wrong with my code?
card2 and card3 function recive each variable inside each click function
inside function click2 setcard(card2); click3 setcard(card3); and so on
For some reason it do not work.
var card2 = 0;
var card3 = 0;

function setcard(card2, card3) {
  document.getElementById("truecount").innerHTML = card2 + card3;
}

//functions

function clickplus2() {
  resultado += 2;
  zen += 2;
  cartas += 1;
  valor += 2;
  zenok += 11;

  card2 += 1;
  setresultado(resultado, zen, cartas, valor, zenok);
  setcard(card2);
}
function clickplus3() {
  resultado += 3;
  zen += 2;
  cartas += 1;
  valor += 3;
  zenok += 10;

  card3 += 1;
  setresultado(resultado, zen, cartas, valor, zenok);
  setcard(card3);
}


The parameters card2 and card3 in setcard shadow the global variables, so if you don't pass a second argument to setcard() when you call it, it will always be undefined

setcard(card2, card3) should be like this?

@OtávioBarreto Yes, either do setcard(card2, card3) or remove the parameters from setcard(), so it uses the global variables.

It worked, thank you!

Just a suggestion: It's 2024 now. 1. Don't use implicit global variables in your function. 2. use let or const instead of var to declare variables.

You're confused because you have two different variables called card2 and two different variables called card3

also, you say the function returns undefined ... since you don't return any value in any of your fuctions, this is as expected
